# Multiple image resize with canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've built a drag and drop image uploader.
I want to automatically create thumbnails of each image.
I used html5 canvas, but when I'm uploading 20 or more 2MB images at once, the browser (safari) crashes. When I leave the resize function out, everything works fine.
Any suggestions on how to handle this? Thank you very much!

this is the resize function that is called on every image:

```
if(this.hasFileReader){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    var file = this.file;
    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = reader.result;
        tempImg.onload = function() {

            var MAX_WIDTH = 348;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
            var tempW = tempImg.width;
            var tempH = tempImg.height;
            if (tempW > tempH) {
                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                   tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                   tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                   tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                   tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var data = 'image=' + dataURL + '&name=' + file.name + '&type=' + file.type;
            xhr.send(data);
        }
}
```

Comment: if, when you have many images, you chain the processing instead of doing them all 'at once', you should be ok. Just handle a FIFO stack of your files (using push() and shift() on an array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new canvas element for each image in your batch and canvases are expensive.

Instead, do `var canvas=document.createElement('canvas') once outside the loop.

That way only 1 canvas element is created instead of many.

BTW, when you do canvas.width=tempW inside the loop your canvas is automatically cleared so you don't need to add clearRect.